# Less - responsive scalling of fonts with classes defined

Tags: html, css, less

I'm looking for a smart way to control fonts sizes depending on browser resolution - as reusable ass possible.
So i have done the following:

```
<section>
  <h1>Contact</h1>
</section>
```

And in LESS file i've defined:

```
.h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
}
section h1 {
.h1;
}
```

So, as you see i have .h1 class defined and i can reuse it.
But later i saw that my idea is now working (media queries don't work:)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
.h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

}

.h1 class has 90px always and media queries didn't change font size to 20px.
My question: is this possible to tweak to work ?
This way i can have small amount of reusable classes and change their size in just one place instead of many places.

Thanks.
PS: I've benn using REM's for long time but it's not perfect for me.

Comment: This is because `.h1;` statement *do not* "reuses" all appearance of `.h1` in your files, for instance it does not copy `.h1` defined within the media into your  `section h1`. Well, in short, if you want a media block to come with the `.h1` mixin the media should be a part of it (not in opposite as in your example above).

Comment: E.g. [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.h1()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2090px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40media%20only%20screen%20and%20(max-width%3A%20991px)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2020px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnsection%20h1%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.h1%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: This seems to work - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use a fluid-typography mixin, as show [in this guide](https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/fluid-type-calc-examples/). This page links to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/MadeByMike/pen/RWJyML) showing a less mixin.

Essentially you pass through the font size values you want to scale between and also the screen sizes that the scaling to occur between. Beneath is some code directly from the codepen link:

```
.fluid-type(@property, @min-vw, @max-vw, @min-size, @max-size) {

    @{property}: @min-size;
    
    @media screen and (min-width: @min-vw) {
        @{property}: calc( @min-size ~" + " unit(@max-size - @min-size) ~" * ((100vw - " @min-vw ~") /" unit(@max-vw - @min-vw) ~")" );
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: @max-vw) {
        @{property}: @max-size;
    }

}
```

the way I use it:

```
h1{
  .fluid-type(font-size, @mobileSize, @desktopSize, 36px, 72px);
}
```

credit to [Mike](https://codepen.io/MadeByMike)